# Validate .CS code files in Umbraco

Tags: c#, asp.net, msbuild, teamcity, umbraco

I'm using TeamCity as our CI tool for an Umbraco codebase. As Umbraco uses non-compiled, CodeFile="MyFile.cs" instead of compiled Codebehind files, running compilation tools on the site does not pick up any coding errors.

How has anyone else added verification / validation to a non-compiled codebase of this sort? Is there nothing I can do to check that code is correct as possible? Any tricks of the trade here?

Thanks,
Chris.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For our Umbraco projects we are using web application projects so they do get compiled, this has worked well for us.

Another potential option would be to [pre-compile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398860.aspx) the site, I have used this method on other projects with some success but not with Umbraco.

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you set the .cs files to **Compile** in the project?